# how can i swap arrray of same images using jquery.

Tags: php, jquery

```
<img src= on.jpg id=1>
<img src= on.jpg id=2>
<img src= on.jpg id=3>
<img src= on.jpg id=4>
<img src= on.jpg id=5>
<img src= on.jpg id=6>
```

on each image clik i need to get off image
ie,

if click on first image then i need to swap that on.jpg image with off.jpg
and remains are in same on.jpg

and update this value into the MSQL DB..

```
img_id image
1     off.jpg
2     on.jpg
3     on.jpg
4     on.jpg
5     on.jpg
6     ofn.jpg
```

Comment: What you tried so far? We're here to help, not do your job for you...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img").click(function(event){
  var isOn = (this.src == "on.jpg");
  var newSource = (isOn) ? "off.jpg" : "on.jpg";
  this.src = newSource;
  // Update your MSQL DB using presumably this.id and newSource
});
```

Comment: @KoolKabin: He didn't even include the AJAX code and no server-side code either. I guess it's a good start for the OP.